# MathJax alignment issue

Tags: bug, mathjax

**update:** this issue is connected with Chrome's text zoom feature - see the bottom of this post.

I quite often see this sort of thing:

[image]

Sometimes when I reload the page, the equations will go back to being centred where they should be - but sometimes not. This is with Google Chrome (31.0.1650.57, though it's been an issue for a while) under OS X 10.8.5.

This is with the Math renderer set to "SVG", because I like my equations to be pretty.

The problem is not specific to multiline equations. Here is an example with a single-line one, albeit a rather long one:
[image]

It seems not to happen with all equations, but I'm not sure what the pattern is. I'd say it occurs with more than 50% of them though.

I habitually browse with Chrome's zoom level set to one or two, because my eyesight is quite poor. This problem doesn't occur with the zoom set to the default level, and it also immediately disappears if I change the zoom level, so as a workaround I can quickly change the zoom to something else and back again (`option`-`-` `option`-`+` on my Mac) to get the correct formatting.

Comment: Try to load that page in another web browser.

Comment: Do you put the equations inside an environment, like \begin{gather}\end{gather}?

Comment: @adobe I tried it in safari and didn't see the issue, but since the problem is intermittent in Chrone anyway I'm not sure how much that really tells us...

Comment: Pulsar in this case I just used \\ to separate the lines. I don't think the problem is specific to multiline equations, but it might be - I'll keep an eye out.

Comment: I've never seen that. I use Opera 12.16 on Scientific Linux 6.4.

Comment: Is this *only* when you use the SVG math renderer? With Chrome v32 on a Windows, it looks fine for me in both SVG and HTML/CSS. Have you tried seeing what happens when you use the zoom trigger?

Comment: By right, it should be fixed when you change to HTML/CSS, because the HTML/CSS forces the equation to be squeezed into the width of the question.

Comment: @dimension10 I've only observed it with svg, but I don't use the HTML/CSS renderer much. (I find it ugly.) I'm not sure what the "zoom trigger" is, but I do use Chrome's page zoom feature due to poor eyesight - I'll try switching it off next time I'm at my computer and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Nathaniel: By zoom trigger, I was talking about MathJaX's inbuilt function (right-click, hover on math settings, and you can find it). I was asking if the same problem persists even in the zoom trigger.

Comment: Ha, I just notcied the same thing using the stadnard HTML/CSS renderer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SylFe.png

Comment: Chrome is full of bugs, try to change it for a better browser.

Comment: @Adobe: Like? Like IE8? : )

Comment: Again reproduced: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LVj0k.png

Comment: @Dimensio1n0 lol you wont even be able to load mathjax in IE, try firefox with a Chrome design add-on since you're familiar with Chrome.

Comment: @Adobe: I was joking about IE of course. I've seen only one advantage of firefox, that it is very easy to add MathML. But it is much slower.

Comment: @Dimensio1n0 does your problem disappear if you change the browser's zoom level? (If not I suspect it's a different problem than the one I'm having. Also: apologies for forgetting to try your suggestion of changing the zoom in the first place!)

Comment: @Nathaniel: I don't usually zoom in webpages, so I guess the issue is different, also, I witness it much less often.